# Regex checking whether string contains digits, letters, spaces, new lines and only allowed characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex which will match only if the string contains only of:

- a-z and A-Z (letters)
- 0-9 (digits)
- whitespaces and new lines
- characters: !@#%^*()_-=+[]{};:,.?/

So if my string contains of chars not on this list, the regex should not match.

Examples:

> AS55DSFs2afds23423ASAS as2 /sd/%%% - match
>
> $$ $Sfs dG@?423 - no match (dollar sign not allowed)

Matching letters and digits is easy:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]*)$
```

But I have a problem with whitespaces, new lines and special characters.

**ANSWER**

```
 ^([A-Za-z0-9\s!@#%^*()_\-=+\[\]{};:,.?\/]*)$
```

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace characters are covered with `\s`:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)$
```

For the special characters, you can add them to the above character class individually, but you would need to escape the characters `-`, `[` and `]`:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9\s!@#%^*()_\-=+\[\]{};:,.?/]*)$
```

Comment: OK. It's helpful. What about list of special characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
^[!@#%^*()_=+\[\]{};:,\.\?\/\sA-Za-z0-9-]+$
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: No match in first string (check examples in my question): https://regex101.com/r/iC8qN6/1